# R train function input multiple metrics

Tags: r, roc, accuracy, metric

I want to get multiple metrics results like the code below but it didnt work because of `metric = list("ROC","F1","Accuracy","Kappa")`. It works perfect for `metric="ROC"`.

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5)
seed <- 7
set.seed(seed)
fit.svmRadial <- train(inputs,outputs,  method="svmRadial",metric = list("ROC","F1","Accuracy","Kappa"), trControl=control, fit=FALSE)
set.seed(seed)
fit.knn <- train(inputs,outputs,  method="knn",metric = list("ROC","F1","Accuracy","Kappa") ,trControl=control)
set.seed(seed)
fit.rf <- train(inputs,outputs,  method="rf",metric = list("ROC","F1","Accuracy","Kappa"), trControl=control)

#tüm öğrenme işlemlerinin sonuçlarının karşılaştırılması 
results <- resamples(list(svm=fit.svmRadial, knn=fit.knn, rf=fit.rf))
summary(results)
bwplot(results)
dotplot(results)
confusionMatrix(fit.svmRadial)
confusionMatrix(fit.knn)
confusionMatrix(fit.rf)
```

Comment: I suspect you're using the caret package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the caret package, the `metric` argument defines how the model is optimized.  From the [caret::train documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/train):

> metric     A string that specifies what summary metric will be used to
>   select the optimal model.

Only a single metric can be used as optimization criteria.

If you want to display the performance on other metrics afterwards, once the model has been selected, you can use the confusionMatrix function on that model. It should report all metrics, regardless of the metric that was specifically used for optimization.